# How to prove that a spiral that I have is logarithmic or archimedean?

Tags: calculus, logarithms, circles, geometric-progressions, osculating-circle

I am conducting a research on modelling a spiral.. I know that the shape of the spiral on my pencil shavings is logarithmic indeed, How do i prove that? How do I prove it is logarithmic and not archimedean?
Here are the pictures of the spiral

[image]

[image]

Comment: Draw a ray from the origin. For the Archimedean spiral distances between its consecutive intersections with the ray are same, for the logarithmic spiral they grow geometrically.

Comment: But, based on the spiral above, how do i calculate it considering the fact that the spiral isnt long enough for me to calculate its consecutive intersections whether it grows geometrically or not

Comment: It is long enough to see that consecutive distances are not equal.

Comment: but not long enough to prove that its growing geometrically right?

Comment: "Prove" is a wrong word here. There are infinitely many curves that pass through finitely many points, the best you can do is regression to some preconceived shape. Taking the log of the log spiral equation you can reduce this to linear regression and see how good the fit is. If you really want to *prove* something you need a theoretical model of pencil sharpening. E.g. from images I've seen, shavings' edges look like loxodromes on a cone, and those you can prove project to log spirals, see [projection of loxodrome helical curves of cone](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3524681/152568).

Comment: Ahhh i see that clear things up, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

HINT 1:

For a start, a simpler model is proposed. The pencil shavings are separated by axial length (lam), lie inside two cylinders, from the lead of pencil (start radius $r$ ) to outer radius of wooden cylinder.

Domain (u,0,CutterLen) generates cutter edges of spiral and (th) the rotation of the pencil axis. Suggested parametrization in `Mathematica` code for its shape:

```
{r, lam, al, CutterLen} = {1, 0.2, Pi/6, 2} ;
ParametricPlot3D[{(r + u Sin[al]) Cos[th], (r + u Sin[al]) Sin[th], 
  lam th + u Cos[al]}, {u, 0, CutterLen}, {th, 0, 6 Pi}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> {9, 72}, PlotStyle -> Opacity [.5], 
 PlotLabel -> PencilShavingGLN]
```

From differential geometry an isometric mapping onto a plane/ development can enable finding coordinates and geodesic curvature at u=CutterLen of the curve in its *development* to determine what the curve is.

[image]

Hope someone takes it further from here by  calculations in DG.

HINT2:

Guessing from appearance alone the developed spirals sketched below may as well be involutes. *Constant width* is a property of involutes.

CutterLen across pencil shaving (blue) is constant and equals to arclength between consecutive start point ( Here subtends 45 deg at center).

[image]